# Hash that generates Decimal output for Swift

Tags: swift, cryptography

I want to hashed a `String`  into a hashed object which has some numerical values `NSNumber`/`Int` as an output instead of alpha-numeric values.

The problem is that after digging through swift and some 3rd party library, I'm not able to find any library that suffices our need.

I'm working on a Chat SDK and it takes `NSNumber`/`Int` as unique identifier to co-relate Chat Message and Conversation Message.

> My company demand is not to store any addition field onto the database
>   or change the schema that we have which complicates thing.

A neat solution my team came with was some sort of hashed function that generates number.

```
func userIdToConversationNumber(id:String) -> NSNumber
```

We can use that function to convert `String` to `NSNumber`/`Int`. This `Int` should be produced by that function and probability of colliding should be negligible. Any suggestion on any approach.

Comment: `probability of colliding should be negligible` it is impossible, space of strings is much much bigger than space of any integer

Comment: As others have pointed out, the hash value is already a number, it's an `Int`. Unless you want something else than hash operations, you already have your number to work with.

Comment: `Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution.` From Apple's official doc

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of upvotes of comments above, but they are absolutely wrong if cryptographic hash functions are meant (and I do conclude that from the tag present).

Comment: I don't want to jump to any conclusion by saying it is impossible but you can simulate alpha-number space with integer space. I think integer that will be spit out will be far longer than alpha-numeric world. Plus, I didn't say "it should Never collide". I know that is impossible but one with "minimal colliding". All these info are stored in user specific bucket that means even if collision exist in 1 in 100,000,000. Chances of user having 100 Million friends is unlikely.

Comment: Note that even with a 1/100.000.000 collision probability, a collision can happen with as few as two elements.

Comment: I agree but our whole internet is based upon these shortcomings. SHA256, KECCAK [SHA3], SHA1 all have some probability of collision but hitting that same bucket is highly unlikely. FYI 1 in 100 Million is just a random number to illustrate scale. Appreciate the response.

Comment: By the way, what are the inputs to this planned hash function?

Comment: I know you feel like you don’t have any other choices, but using a hashes for keys is not a great idea, even if collisions are extremely rare. And if you’re dealing with a firm that is, by fiat, placing constraints on you, they don’t strike me as the sort of organization that will look kindly on a decision like this in retrospect. It strikes as one of those ideas that you’re likely to regret in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key calculation you need to perform is the birthday bound. My favorite table is the one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics), and I reference it regularly when I'm designing systems like this one.

The table expresses how many items you can hash for a given hash size before you have a certain expectation of a collision. This is based on a perfectly uniform hash, which a cryptographic hash is a close approximation of.

So for a 64-bit integer, after hashing 6M elements, there is a 1-in-a-million chance that there was a *single* collision anywhere in that list. After hashing 20M elements, there is a 1-in-a-thousand chance that there was a single collision. And after 5 billion elements, you should bet on a collision (50% chance).

So it all comes down to how many elements you plan to hash and how bad it is if there is a collision (would it create a security problem? can you detect it? can you do anything about it like change the input data?), and of course how much risk you're willing to take for the given problem.

Personally, I'm a 1-in-a-million type of person for these things, though I've been convinced to go down to 1-in-a-thousand at times. (Again, this is not 1:1000 chance of any *given* element colliding; that would be horrible. This is 1:1000 chance of there being a collision *at all* after hashing some number of elements.) I would not accept 1-in-a-million in situations where an attacker can craft arbitrary things (of arbitrary size) for you to hash. But I'm very comfortable with it for structured data (email addresses, URLs) of constrained length.

If these numbers work for you, then what you want is a hash that is highly uniform in all its bits. And that's a SHA hash. I'd use a SHA-2 (like SHA-256) because you should always use SHA-2 unless you have a good reason not to. Since SHA-2's bits are all independent of each other (or at least that's its intent), [you can select any number of its bits to create a shorter hash](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9436). So you compute a SHA-256, and take the top ([or bottom](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/161/should-i-use-the-first-or-last-bits-from-a-sha-256-hash/163#163)) 64-bits as an integer, and that's your hash.

As a rule, for modest sized things, you can get away with this in 64 bits. You cannot get away with this in 32 bits. So when you say "NSNumber/Int", I want you to mean explicitly "64-bit integer." For example, on a 32-bit platform, Swift's Int is only 32 bits, so I would use UInt64 or uint64_t, not Int or NSInteger. I recommend unsigned integers here because these are really unique bit patterns, not "numbers" (i.e. it is not meaningful to add or multiply them) and having negative values tends to be confusing in identifiers unless there is some semantic meaning to it.

Note that everything said about hashes here is also true of random numbers, if they're generated by a cryptographic random number generator. In fact, I generally use random numbers for these kinds of problems. For example, if I want clients to generate their own random unique IDs for messages, how many bits do I need to safely avoid collisions? (In many of my systems, you may not be able to use all the bits in your value; some may be used as flags.)

That's my general solution, but there's an even better solution if your input space is constrained. If your input space is smaller than 2^64, then you don't need hashing at all. Obviously, any Latin-1 string up to 8 characters can be stored in a 64-bit value. But if your input is even more constrained, then you can compress the data and get slightly longer strings. It only takes 5 bits to encode 26 symbols, so you can store a 12 letter string (of a single Latin case) in a UInt64 if you're willing to do the math. It's pretty rare that you get lucky enough to use this, but it's worth keeping in the back of your mind when space is at a premium.

I've built a lot of these kinds of systems, and I will say that eventually, we almost always wind up just making a longer identifier. You can make it work on a small identifier, but it's always a little complicated, and there is nothing as effective as just having more bits.... Best of luck till you get there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a hashes that are collision resistant using a cryptographic hash function. The output of such a hash function is in bits if you follow the algorithms specifications. However, implementations will generally only return bytes or an encoding of the byte values. A hash does *not* return a number, as other's have indicated in the comments.

It is relatively easy to convert such a hash into a number of 32 bites such as an `Int` or `Int32`. You just take the leftmost bytes of the hash and interpret those to be an unsigned integer.

However, a cryptographic hash has a relatively *large output size* precisely to make sure that the chance of collisions is small. Collisions are prone to the birthday problem, which means that you only have to try about 2 to the power of hLen divided by 2 inputs to create a collision within the generated set. E.g. you'd need 2^80 tries to create a collision of RIPEMD-160 hashes.

Now for most cryptographic hashes, certainly the common ones, the same rule counts. That means that for 32 bit hash that you'd only need 2^16 hashes to be reasonably sure that you have a collision. That's not good, 65536 tries are very easy to accomplish. And somebody may get lucky, e.g. after 256 tries you'd have a 1 in 256 chance of a collision. That's no good.

So calculating a hash value to use it as ID is fine, but you'd need the full output of a hash function, e.g. 256 bits of SHA-2 to be very sure you don't have a collision. Otherwise you may need to use something line a serial number instead.